# IIS returning 503 "Service Unavailable" on all Virtual Directories under the Default Web Site, but all Applications using the same app pool work

Tags: iis-7.5

I've got a webserver that's recently started returning 503 "Service Unavailable" for all requests made to any virtual directories under the "Default web Site".  These virtual directories had been working for months without issue. There are a few Applications set up on this server, both under the Default Web Site as well.  On of them has it's own Application Pool, while the other is using the Default Application Pool, same as the Default Web Site. These Applications are working normally.

If I create a new Virtual Directory, I get 503s. If I create a new Application, it works normally.  I've tried creating a new Application Pool for the Default Web Site with no success. I've bounced IIS as well as the whole server.  I compared the applicationHost.config of this server to another working server and  nothing jumped out at me as out of the ordinary. I'm also not seeing any errors or warnings in the Windows event logs relating to this.

I'm tempted to just re-create all of the virtual directories as applications, just to get things functional again, but that's not really fixing the issue.

I'm happy to provide any additional information as requested.

Edit:
We discovered that if we changed the http binding to anything other than port 80, then the Default Web Site would serve pages from the root, but would still respond with 503 for all requests to any of the virtual directories.  Changing the https binding had no effect.  We also tried removing the http:80 binding on the Default, and created a new site with an http:80 binding.  When we did this, the new site worked as expected.

Comment: Have you tried changing the identity under which the app pool runs to something other than ApplicationPoolIdentity? When the 503 occurs, does the app pool stop? Check the application logs in event viewer to see what is behind the 503, there should be a more detailed message.

Comment: @dartonw Changing the identity had no effect.  The app pool does not stop when the error occurs and there are no relevant entries in the application's logs.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the "Application" view under "Windows Logs" in event viewer. Also check the httperr logs at %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR.

Comment: @dartonw No need to apologize, I actually understood what you meant, but was unclear in my response; The Windows logs are devoid of pertinent errors.  And I did look in the httper logs, which are filled with entries like:
`2014-09-22 16:27:44 10.4.100.21 44985 10.4.144.112 80 HTTP/0.9 GET / 503 1 N/A DefaultAppPool`

Comment: Weird. This can occur if virtual directories in an app pool are running different versions of ASP.NET but that usually stops the app pool. If you're running ASP.NET apps you might try "aspnet_regiis -r" from the appropriate framework directory.

Comment: I've had a similar problem with virtual dirs when I added https to the default website. When I removed https I had left Enbaled Protocols = "http https", when I left only http virtual dirs worked again.